# Prove that $(R ∪ R^{-1}) _{k^2}$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ is a binary relation on set a $S$ and let $R_0, R_1, R_2 \dots$ be defined as follows.

$$\begin{align} R_0 & := \Delta_{S} = \{(x,x) : x ∈ S\} \\ R_{n+1} & := R_n ∪ (R;R_n), && \text{for } n \geq 0 \end{align}.$$

There exists $i ∈ N$ such that $R_i = R_{i+1}.$

If $|S| = k,$ show that $(R ∪ R^{-1}) _{k^2}$ is an equivalence relation.

I know that I just have to prove that $(R ∪ R^{-1}) _{k^2}$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. But with the given information, I don't know how to approach this to come up with a formal proof.

Comment: The expression containing  $k^2$ is meaningless.

Comment: That is actually R raised to a backward arrow, but I didn't know how to get that symbol in there. So I used -1 instead. And I thought 'inverse' and 'converse' are the same for a relation? I could be wrong.

Comment: What stands $R_n ∪ (R;R_n)$ for, especially $(R;R_n)$?

Comment: ; stands for composition of relations here.